# Find out the title and artist of a song in Ruby

Tags: ruby, audio, sound-recognition

I've found an interesting gem to discover from an unknown file which music it comes from returning the title and the artist : https://github.com/tenderlove/earworm

The fact is the last commit was 4 years ago and the website used is no longer working...

Does anyone know of another solution for this problem ? Another gem or another snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use taglib. I used it in my [mylastfavourite](https://github.com/matthiasbeyer/mylastfavourite) script and it works really good and fast.

It reads mp3 tags. If you search for a gem which takes the stuff from a webservive, you could try [rbrainz](http://rbrainz.rubyforge.org/) for example. I never worked with this before.